# assigning value to a double dimensional vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

```
vector<vector<int>> queue_and_stack(vector<int> A, int n)
{
    // Write your code here
    int i, j, k;
    j = 0;
    k = 0;

    vector<vector<int>> myVector;
    int chec;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        chec = prime(A[i]);
        if (chec == 1)
        {
            myVector[0][j] = A[i];
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            myVector[1][k] = A[i];
            k++;
        }
    }
    return myVector;
}
```

I want to assign value to myVector but i dont know what size it should have , i dont know what is wrong with the code , but it giving rubbish value on runtime.

Comment: Vectors have a feature of dynamic memory allocation. It's totally up to you to define a size for it in runtime or during compilation.

Comment: so is my code correct myVector[0][j] = A[i]; , coz it's not working

Comment: You need to push back the elements, that's what you're not doing. Just leaving the vectors empty.

Comment: Harshit: No, `myVector` is empty when you make it. Use [`push_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) to add an empty row and then add whatever you want into that row.

Comment: Are you sure you want to copy the input vector instead of using reference and specify the number of elements to deal with instead of just using `A.size()`?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi  I did tried this myVector[0].push_back(A[i]); but its not working.

Comment: @MikeCAT yes i want to sort the elemets on A on some basis in 1st and 2nd row of myVector , I know the size of vector A (say 5) , but not the size of myVector it can be anything [2,3] ,[3,2] ,[1,4] etc.

Comment: `myVector[0].push_back(A[i]);` tries to push into a nonexistent vector because `myVector[0]` isn't anything yet. Push an empty `vector<int>` into `myVector` before pushing an `int` into the `vector<int>` that you just created. Or preallocate 2 `vector<int>`s  in `myVector` by initializing it the way MikeCAT suggested in their answer

Comment: @PranavHosangadi oh it worked thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `vector<vector<int> > myVector;`, `myVector` has no elements, so you have to add elements.

Try this:

```
vector<vector<int> > queue_and_stack (vector<int> A,int n) {
    // Write your code here
    int i;

    vector<vector<int> > myVector(2); // allocate 2 empty vectors
    int chec;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        chec = prime(A[i]);
        if(chec == 1)
        {
            myVector[0].push_back(A[i]); // add element whose value is A[i] to myVector[0]

        }
        else
        {
            myVector[1].push_back(A[i]); // add element whose value is A[i] to myVector[1]

        }
    }
    return myVector;
}
```

Comment: its not working , same problem , giving rubbish value during runtime , also working fine without that line myVector[0].push_back(A[i]);  myVector[1].push_back(A[i]);

Comment: @HarshitGupta [This code should work](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ivPzYYztJdiahhe3). Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including the caller if you want us to find the cause.

Comment: thanx mike , it worked , but can you please tell me what myVector(2) is doing , is it creating 2 rows for the vector , thnx

Comment: @HarshitGupta It is creating 2 elements (vectors) and default-initializing them using [the constructor of `std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).